# Ubuntu 12.04 AllowOverride All throws Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I just created my server and I need to use .htaccess files, one of them worked and another one didn't... Apparently for .htaccess to work you need to enable AllowOverride, and so I did under: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` Changed this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

To this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I restart apache my whole site now throws error `500 Internal Server Error`

My .htaccess file contains this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Do you have something in your htaccess ?

Comment: Yes, sorry just added it!

Comment: Did you enable **mod_rewrite** ? What if your htaccess is empty ?

Comment: Of course, I thought I did, thank you! If you submit answer I will approve it!

Comment: I believe this question belongs to Serverfault not Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your apache config seems fine to me.

You get `500 Internal Server Error` which means your `htaccess` is now executed.
If you didn't enable **mod_rewrite** you get such errors.

Should be working as expected once *mod_rewrite* enabled.
Also, don't forget to add a `RewriteBase` (which will prevent future problems with virtual directories)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Where is the file with containing word RewriteBase ?